# How can i run a piece of code every number of days

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently developing an app in swift and I was wondering if there is a way to run a piece of code every number of days locally on the users phone? An example of this is that i would run a piece of code every 5 days.

Comment: What platform is this for?

Comment: Yep i've added it to the question now and Swift

Comment: No, like is this for a mac? a phone? open source swift on a server?

Comment: Locally on the user phone

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to perform tasks in the background permanently at the interval of time you are requesting. There is a time limit of 10 or 15 minutes for background tasks to complete.

**Is it something special you want to do in the background?** For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must request specific permissions to run them in the background without their being suspended.

You can read more about background execution [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

If you want to run something when the phone is active you can do that by checking the `applicationDidBecomeActive`function in your AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, you don't have control over when an app is opened, and your app cannot arbitrarily load itself to run code (unless a push notification is involved).

That being said, you can use one of the methods in `AppDelegate` to check if 5 or more days have passed since the date the code was last run (which you can store in `UserDefaults`), and run if if it has.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure there more efficient ways of doing this since I am just a beginner but I might as well try to help. Could you create an NSTimer that fires every x amount of days. The `NSTimeInterval` would be 60 (seconds) * 60 (minutes) * 24 (hours) * (number of days you desire). And then the `Selector` would be "(whatever your function's name is)". Finally, whatever you want to happen every x days would be what you put inside the function that is the `Selector` in the `NSTimer` that would most likely go in your `override func viewDidLoad() {}` I hope this helps you and future viewers.

Comment: first of all: your answer would benefit from formatting. second: 24*60*60 is wrong. due to DST days may be 23, 24 or 25 hours long.